# "errorMessage": "[Errno 28] No space left on device" AWS-Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I am executing my test configuration and this is the error I am facing. I have a trained model of size 327mb and layers of 250mb required for the inference of my Text To Speech trained model. So the size of model and layers might be the reason?? Please help me clarify and provide a solution.
I am importing the trained model from s3 bucket and then loading it for the further processing.

Comment: yes, you are running out of lambda disk space. You can try switching to EFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambdas local storage in `/tmp` is only `512MB`. You are apparently exceeding this limit.

There are five solutions I can think of:

1. [Mount a EFS volume](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) (which already contains your trained model) to the Lambda.
2. Reduce the size of your model.
3. Stream the model in chunks to your Lambda (might be hard).
4. Not use Lambda (maybe just a plain EC2 or EKS).
5. [Use a Docker container that already contains your model as Lambda.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)

It is hard to tell what the best solution for you is, since so much information is missing. But those solutions should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please tell me What more information is required? I can provide it. I'll try switching to EFS, hope it might resolve the issue. Also, I cant figure out how to locate my /tmp folder in lambda function and I am also loading a waveglow pretrained model from github using `torch.hub.load`  and it gives me module initialization error. It would be very helpful for me if these issues are also resolved.

Comment: @HasanKhan You probably need to go with either option 1 or 5. Furthermore, you should not download things during the _runtime_ of your Lambda that you could package during the build time of your Lambda. So either put your models on the EFS volume that you mount or download them when you build the docker image. Only data that changes often or between requests or depends on the request etc. should be downloaded during the runtime of your Lambda. Furthermore, the `/tmp` folder is not on your local machine. It is part of the server running the Lambda. Try `os.listdir("/tmp")` to show contents.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try to implement the suggested solutions. Just one last thing I want to know that if I'm implementing a lambda function so the model have to be inside the lambda function or outside for inferencing. Actually, I'm implementing a text to speech trained model to produce audio files so is that possible to deploy on lambda and whether the calling of model is correct or incorrect?  I have got two models one is a trained text to speech named as tacotron and other is waveglow.